# Add elements to set from multiple thread

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I am having a `Set` and I am adding unique elements to it using multiple `Threads`. In each run, the size of the `Set` varies from 295 to 299.

```
        Set<String> ids = new HashSet<>();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                ids.add("Id" + i);
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 100; i < 200; i++) {
                ids.add("Id" + i);
            }
        });

        Thread t3 = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 200; i < 300; i++) {
                ids.add("Id" + i);
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
        System.out.println(ids.size());
```

Though I am not using the `thread-safe` collection as I am adding unique elements I am expecting the size should be always consistent.

I know how to fix this issue(use `Set<String> ids = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();`), but I am trying to understand why I am getting inconsistent sizes?

Comment: The question should be the other way round: on what basis are you “expecting the size should be always consistent” despite knowingly using a construct that is not thread safe?

Comment: @Holger I am adding unique elements and so I am expecting a consistent size.

Comment: You are using a class that is known to be *not thread safe* from multiple threads. There is nothing you can expect. End of the story.

Comment: My thoughts; HashSet know the size of itself by looking the map (HashMap). HashMap has transient size variable. It's increases value like ++size. Is ++size atomic? I think this is the problem.

Comment: Transient is for serialization and has nothing to do with concurrency.